# Creating a new variable that counts number of variables whose values fall within a range

Tags: stata

I am trying to create a new variable that counts the number of temperature variables whose value falls within a certain range of the temperature.

For example, my data looks like this -

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKPmL.png)

I would like to create a new variable that counts the number of days where the temperature was within 30°C - 31.9°C. I tried to use `egen` - `anycount()` in Stata but it won't accept non-integers in the numlist.

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you provide more structure to your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/how-to-create-high-quality-reproducible-examples-in-stata

Comment: Your example seem to imply that you want 2 degree bins, but (1) testing for equality with non-integers can easily run into precision problems (2) what about values between 31.9 and 32?  See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0095 for emphasis on rounding as (ofren) a better way to binning.

Comment: @ArthurMorris is right. For example, your image isn't even Stata output: it looks like something you cooked up in a spreadsheet. The Stata tag wiki has very detailed advice, the most important detail being to use `dataex` to give a data example as Stata code.

Comment: I think I might be working on 5-degree bins,  but thank you for the link. And yes, I meant to round them off.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the variables:

```
local vars T* // since your variables are named with this convention

generate count = 0
foreach v of local vars {
    replace count = count + 1 if inrange(`v', 30, 31.9)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer that answers your question, and edit the question to clarify as Nick suggests.